# WPF Telerik TreeListView not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have an application that uses a RadTreeListView from Telerik as it's main display.  It works great most of the time.  However I have small handful of users that are reporting that it's just blank sometimes. I have one user that has 2 basically identical computers and it happens on one and not the other.  I asked Telerik but they asked for a simplified version which may be kind of difficult to do considering the sporadic nature of the issue.  I know this is pretty open ended but has anyone ever seen something like that before using their controls (or any controls for that matter)?

I'm at a bit of a loss so any help or direction would be appreciated.  Not sure if it's any help but here is the code for the main template used for the UI:

```
            <telerik:RadTreeListView BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-1,0,0" AutoExpandItems="False" EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                                     EnableColumnVirtualization="True" IsDragTooltipEnabled="False" Initialized="TLV_Main_Initialized"
                                 x:Name="TLV_Main" FontFamily="{Binding TVFont}" ItemsSource="{Binding Keynotes}" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                                 GridLinesVisibility="None" IsExpandedBinding="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource TLV_Standard}" SelectionMode="Extended" IsReadOnly="True" RowIsExpandedChanged="rowExpandedChanged"
                                 IsDragDropEnabled="True" kd:TreeViewDragDropBehavior.IsEnabled="True" PreviewMouseDown="TLV_Main_PreviewMouseDown">
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="{Binding myDB.Commands.CmdDelete}" />
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.InputBindings>
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.SortDescriptors>
                    <telerik:SortDescriptor Member="SortingKey" SortDirection="Ascending" />
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.SortDescriptors>
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.DragCueItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Width="250">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyValue}" Margin="5,0" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.DragCueItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn IsVisible="False" DataMemberBinding="{Binding SortingKey}" />
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Key" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource st_CellTopJustify}" 
                                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource dt_Column_KeyEditable}" />
                    <telerik:GridViewColumn Header="Description" Width="*" CellTemplate="{StaticResource dt_Column_Description}" />
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.Columns>
                <telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                    <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNotes}" />
                </telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
            </telerik:RadTreeListView>
```

Comment: For anyone interested I think I have narrowed this down to a conflict with another addin.  My program is actually an addin to another primary program and I believe the users experiencing this also have another addin installed that is using another version of the Telerik controls and it's causing a conflict.  I will post back when I know for sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmed that this issue is caused by a conflict with another addin to the main program.  They were using a different version of the Telerik libraries than I was and since theirs was loaded first it 'won' and my version didn't get loaded.  Once their addin was removed mine works fine.  If anyone knows of a fix for this I would love to hear it.  For now I have contacted the other company and we are going to make an effort to unify our versions for future releases, but there may be others out there using this that may come across the same issue...